# How to remove footer view in Android?

Tags: android, pagination

I have three buttons and I'm displaying pagination with button wise. If i click on button one calling the pagination one , if click on button 2 start the pagination 2nd , if click on button 3rd  start the pagination 3rd its all working . I have add progress bar at the end of the listView setOnScrollListener per pagination.

But the problem is whenever go to the end of the list View progress bar is added every time.I'm tried to remove the footer view at the last page then getting exception of `inValid index out of bound exception index 0`.

Can someone help me how to work properly with pagination with progress bar.

```
1st button click = Pegination();
same as to 2nd button click =LoginUser_PostLoacalPages();
And same as to 3rd button click = R_Post_Pagination();


    Here is 1st pagination 


public void Pegination() {

            final int activityCount  = sharedPreferences.getInt("ActivityListCount", 0);
            Log.e("","activityCount in Pegination method ="+activityCount);

            footer = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.prohressbar, listView, false);
            rLayout = (RelativeLayout) footer.findViewById(R.id.progressRel);
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) footer.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            btnLoadMore = (Button) footer.findViewById(R.id.btnLoadMore);
            btnLoadMore.getLayoutParams().height = 0;
            progressBar.getLayoutParams().height = 130;
            btnLoadMore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            listView.addFooterView(footer);

    listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        private int total;

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int scrollState) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int firstItem, int visibleItemCount, final int totalItems) {

            total = firstItem + visibleItemCount;
            Log.e("", "total =" + total);

            if (totalItems > 0 && total > 0 && total == totalItems) {
                if (preLast != total) {
                    if (pageCount < LocalPages) {
                        Handler handler = new Handler();
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                pageCount++;
                                 for (All_Post all_Post : allDesc) {
                    descArray.add(all_Post);
                                }
                                if (adapter != null) {
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                                    listView.setSelection(totalItems);
                                }
                            }
                        }, 2500);
                    }
                    preLast = total;
                    Log.e("", "11111111111 preLast=" + preLast);
                }

                preLast = total;
                Log.e("", "222222222222222 preLast=" + preLast);
                if (pageCount == LocalPages)
                {
                    if (preLast == total)
                    {

                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            btnLoadMore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            btnLoadMore.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 60));
                            pageCount = 0;

                       }

                    }
            }
            }
        }
   });}
```

Comment: try this http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-listview-with-load-more-button/